# Angularjs - read inside json file

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

This is my first attempt with angularjs and ionic-framework.

I have an example json file and i'd like to display onscreen some data from it.
The displaying-data bit works, but i'd like to populate a "details" page with some info that are stored as an abject inside the main json file, and i need to use the id from the url to select to display only the data that i need.

Here's some code:

**App.js**

```
angular.module('hgapp', ['ionic', 'hgapp.controllers', 'ngResource'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.details', {
            url: '/details/:roomID',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
                    controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module('hgapp.controllers', ['hgapp.services'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, HGJson) {
    HGJson.get(function (data) {
        $scope.rooms = data.data;
    })
})

.controller('DetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, HGJson) {
    $scope.roomID = $stateParams.roomID;
    console.log($stateParams.roomID);
})
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('hgapp.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('HGJson', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('json/data.json')
});
```

**Data.json (Just a simplified example)**

```
{
   tm: 00000000,
   errors: 0,
   data: {
       {id: 0, name: Value 0, url:url-0},
       {id: 1, name: Value 1, url:url-1},
       {id: 2, name: Value 2, url:url-2}
}
```

**details.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Details">
<ion-content>
    <h1>{{roomID}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

In the details page i'm printing the roomID just to see if the controller (detailsCtrl) works, and i have the correct id printed every time. Now, the bit where i'm stuck is how to manipulate the data from HGJson service so that it allows my to print on data from the right room id.

I hope this question is clear enought, if not, feel free to ask for more clarification.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

At the end i solved it adding this to my controller.js file:

```
.controller('DetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, HGJson) {
    HGJson.get(function (data) {
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (item) {
            if (item.id == $stateParams.roomID)
                $scope.currentRoom = item;
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Have you tried the `json` filter? In your html: `{{roomID | json}}`

Comment: the result adding json filter is this -> "6" (for roomID = 6). Nothing else, it just adds the speachmarks

Comment: What happens if you try `{{rooms | json}}`. Do you see the data from data.json?

Comment: yes, with {{rooms | json }} i can see the data but for all the rooms, and not only for the one that i want (id:6)

Comment: ok, I'll add an answer, give me a few mins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same thing as what you're doing in the app controller, but find the room you want in the returned JSON:

```
HGJson.get(function (data) {
    $scope.room = data.data.filter(function(room) {
      return room.id == $stateParams.roomID);
    })[0];
});
```

You could also put that filtering functionality in your service, so that in the future, when you have a real dynamic backend, you call a different URL returning only the requested room rather than calling a URL that returns all the rooms.

```
angular.module('hgapp.services')
.factory('HGJson', function ($http) {
    return {
      getRooms: function() {
        return $http.get('json/data.json').then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
        });
      },
      getRoom: function(roomId) {
        return $http.get('json/data.json').then(function(response) {
          return response.data.data.filter(function(room) {
            return room.id == roomID;
          })[0];
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Note that your JSON is invalid: data must be an array, not an object.

Comment: 1) Thanks for the suggestion about the json, it is actually wrong only in thes questoion but not on my dev machine
2) Can you provide an example for adding filtering on services? or something i can read more about it? thanks

Comment: I can't use your code, it generates tons of errors in the console and i'm not able to retrive any data anymore

Comment: seams like there is something wrong in getRoom(roomId)

Comment: It should be fixed now. But you shouldn't use my code. Not before you have understood it.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you will need to create a function to "find" the correct object in your data object.

Try something like this:

```
$scope.getRoom = function(id) {
  for(var i in $scope.rooms) {
    if($scope.rooms[i].id === id) {
      return $scope.rooms[i];
    }
  }
};
```

And you can display it in your DOM:

```
{{ getRoom(roomID) }}
```

**BUT** it would probably be even better to set the current room to a scoped variable instead of running the function every time. So in this case (*I strongly recommend*), instead of returning `$scope.rooms[i]`, you could set `angular.copy($scope.rooms[i], $scope.currentRoom)` (this will copy the room into the `currentRoom` scoped variable) and then use it in the DOM with simply `{{ currentRoom }}`

Good luck!

Comment: I assume the getRoom function need to go inside the detailsCtrl, right?

Comment: but, like in my recommendation, I would find the room when the data loads, and set it to `currentRoom` instead, so you're not always computing the getRooms

Comment: i tried like you said but i have a blank page...nothing is returned at all (even adding json) tried with the currentRoom Scope as you recommended)

Comment: sorry, it should be in the appCtrl, since that is where `$scope.rooms` lives

Comment: but then it won't be available in my template cause it is controlled by detailsCtrl, am i right?

Comment: If you need `rooms` data in your detailsCtrl, then move the `HGJson.get` call there... If you need it in both places, then you should consider using a custom directive instead of having controllers everywhere

Comment: I think i need it in both places as i have a menu bar alway available with some data, and some other data inside the detailsCtrl...i'm gonna read about custom directives in angular now

Comment: This is a good read on custom directive: http://ng-learn.org/tags/directives.html also this video helped me tons https://youtu.be/UMkd0nYmLzY

Comment: thank you very much, i'm going to read that article and watch that video.
:)

Comment: I tried inspecting the console, adding some debugger, and i noticed that basically when it reaches getRoom = function, it just don't go inside the function for some reason...any thoughts?

Comment: The debugger won't 'go into' getRoom until it is invoked with `getRoom()`. Those parentheses are the difference